# Given that regular functions on a projective variety are locally constant, show that $\mathbb{P}^n$ is not affine.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am not working with schemes. A variety is affine if it is isomorphic to $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$ where $Z$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb A^n$.

> Proposition: If $(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ is a projective variety then the regular functions are locally constant functions. In particular if $X$ is connected $\mathcal{O}_X=k$.

Using this proposition I want to show that $\mathbb{P}^n$ is not affine.

Suppose $\mathbb P^n$ was affine then we have $(\mathbb P^n, \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb P^n})$ is isomorphic to some affine variety $(Z,\mathcal{O}_Z)$, call this isomorphism $\varphi$.
Since $\varphi$ is an isomorphism of algebraic varieties, in particular we get that it is a homomorphism of topological spaces.

Now I think next should construct some regular function no $Z$ and use the isomorphism of algebraic varieties to pull this back to what should be a regular function on $\mathbb P^n$. But I'm not sure how to construct such a function. If you could tell me how to think about doing such a thing that would be great. There are other ways we can see $\mathbb P^n$ is not an affine variety but I am interested in getting used to working with these properties of morphisms of algebraic varieties.

This is how I am thinking about the problem if you could tell me how I'm going wrong or where to continue that would be great!

- we want to construct a regular function on some subset of $Z$ that pulls back to a non locally constant function. This gives us a contradiction and we are done.
- in the affine variety the regular functions are the locally rational functions
- we don't know what $Z$ looks like so we can't local coordiantes on $Z$ and construct a regular function using those coordinates
- even if we did how do we know that this doesn't pull back to something that is locally constant

Comment: In $Z \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ (which is irreducible), there are two cases... either every coordinate map is locally constant (hence constant), and $Z$ is thus a point, or any of them is a not-locally constant regular function.

Comment: How do we know that when we pull back some not-locally constant regular function, it will still be not locally constant?

Comment: Since it’s an isomorphism, the pullback on $\mathbb{P}^n$ of *any* global function on $Z$ is a global function, hence a scalar. Thus every global function on $Z$ is a scalar so $Z$ is a point.

Comment: Sorry I worded my confusion wrong. Let $f$ be any global function of $Z$. Its pull back $g$ is a global function on $\mathbb P^n$, therefore $g$ is a scalar. Why is $f$ then a scalar? I feel I am missing some very silly.

Comment: Because we have an isomorphism of varieties $Z \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$, the pullback on global functions has to be injective.